# PermissionError: [WinError 5] Отказано в доступе:"path/to/file.txt. Что делать?

Tags: python, файлы, listbox

```
def delete_1(list):
    g = list.curselection()
    try:
        print(list.get(g[0]))
        list.delete(g[0])
        file_path = r'text_files\\{}'.format(str(list.get(g[0])))
        os.remove(file_path)
    except IndexError:
        pass
```

Товарищи, столкнулся с проблемой удаления файла. При исполнении кода вылазит ошибка

> PermissionError: [WinError 5] Отказано в доступе:
> "path/to/example.txt".

Запускал через консоль от имени администратора, антивирус тоже не вмешивался. В интернете видел, что люди также встречались с этой проблемой, но внятного решения я не нашёл. Если что, я новичок и только начал изучение работы с файлами. Поможете?

Comment: Покажите, пожалуйста, вывод программы

Comment: При компиляции или при исполнении ошибка? Непонятно.

Comment: File "C:/Users/HOME/Desktop/Блокнот/main_update_01.py", line 50, in delete_1
    os.remove(file_path)
PermissionError: [WinError 5] Отказано в доступе: 'text_files\\\\' вот вывод при исполнении кода

Comment: вы просто пытаетесь удалить то, чего нет. рабочий каталог у вас может быть совсем иным, а путь вы указали относительный. укажите полный путь к каталогу.  так же вы не сможете удалить директорию, если она является текущей для какого-нибудь процесса.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Проблема была, как я понял, в постановке команд. Дело в том, что я сначала удаляю элемент, а потом пытаюсь его снова получить. То есть код в итоге должен выглядеть вот так:`

```
def delete_1(list):
    g = list.curselection()
    try:
        file_path = r'text_files\\' + list.get(g[0])
        list.delete(g[0])
        print(file_path)
        os.remove(file_path)
    except IndexError:
        pass`
```